# Google App Engine backends

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

I have a page which uses some data from datastore, and if the data is outdated it should trigger update. The updates takes up about some minutes, so I decided to do it in a backend. However, when I use `urlfetch.fetch(backends.get_url('backend-name'))`, the page shows `500 Internal Server Error`, and in logs I see `DeadlineExceededError` from this line of script. And one more thing: the deployed backend seems to be running and wasting `Backend Hours` even if not used.

Google documentation on this topic hasn't full examples, and I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: What are you trying todo with the fetch?

Comment: If your backend is not dynamic, you will pay for every seconds its up even if its not doing anything.

Comment: I have no idea about other ways of starting backends (without fetch). Are there any?

Comment: So was there any improvements? I have the same issue! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937556/start-backend-with-async-urlfetch-on-google-app-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backend is a context where your handlers can run, you can execute an handler on a backend by using the [taskqueue.add()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/functions#add) with the target parameter set to your backend name.
This will execute the handler on the backend allowing it to live for more then ten minute and have more memory.

Comment: I've looked through GAE documentation, but I can't figure out how exactly to combine backends and taskqueues. Can you please provide a simple example of this kind of thing?

Comment: @chersanya Just write a simple handler that does all the processing job and queue it using taskqueue.add(url='<path to handler>', target='<backend name>')

Comment: Thanks, it seem to work. But where can I find the logs from such handler? The handler contains `logging.info('TestLog'); logging.flush()`, but I can't see them anywhere.

Comment: @chersanya look for a combo box in the top left corner of the dashboard, switch to your backend name.

Comment: I do not understand why you use a backend for an update. A taskqueue can run 10 minutes and if that is not enough, you can chain them.

Comment: @voscausa backend can maintain state in memory, and can have larger memory

Comment: The OP didn't say he needed more memory or state, just more time. A task queue task should work just fine, and will be way cheaper.

Comment: Any help for me as well? @ShayErlichmen have similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937556/start-backend-with-async-urlfetch-on-google-app-engine
The worst is that there are no examples for backends and thus making it difficult for people not in this kind of philosophy.